# Quit terminal but store the session for next start

Tags: terminal

When I restart Mac, I have the option of restart the applications which will quit. This approach brings back all the terminal windows with all info such as terminal old commands and output, their current directory, etc from before quitting the application.

**Is the above approach possible for manually quitting the terminal application using CMD+Q?**

Application of this: This will allow me to quit the terminal when I am working on non-developer tasks but allow me to jump back easily, no more CD to each folder and history will allow me to get back in the zone of various tasks I was doing in each tab(db session, test data, git commit's etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a system-wide pref to let apps save their state at quit, similar to that for reboot 'reopen windows when logging back in'.

System Prefs > General - uncheck 'Close windows when quitting an app'

[image]

<sup>Picture from El Capitan, but the pref has been there since maybe Mavericks</sup>